# What is the // comparator in ruby? Does it exist

Tags: ruby, comparison, string-comparison, comparison-operators

I am new to Ruby and using codecademy to start my learning. I am on the topic of comparators / relational operators and have been given an example with `//` as a comparator. Am i reading what codecademy is asking me wrong? Because I can't find anywhere what `//` means and i can't remember doing it.

If it does exist what does it mean please?

Comment: Maybe if you could copy-paste the example here it would be easier to say what it means.

Comment: AFAIK it is used in `regex` and `.grep(//)`, since it compares strings within them, it is termed as comparator

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. i was confused as actually it was not supposed to be a comparator in the example i was looking at. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

A *comparator* is an operator which compares two values, but there is no `//` operator in Ruby.

Maybe you confuse it with `||`? While this is not a comparator, it is at least an **operator**.

BTW, the token `//` **does** exist in Ruby. It just is not an operator, but a regular expression literal. It denotes a regexp, which matches any string.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. i was confused as actually it was not supposed to be a comparator in the example i was looking at. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as a `//` operator in Ruby. It simply isn't legal syntax:

```
1 // 2
# unterminated regexp meets end of file
# syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_END, expecting tSTRING_CONTENT or tREGEXP_END or tSTRING_DBEG or tSTRING_DVAR
```

As you can see, it is treated as a [`Regexp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html) [literal](http://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html).

It would only be legal as a `Regexp` literal, for example like this:

```
// =~ 'foo'
'foo' =~ //
'foo'.split(//) #=> ['f', 'o', 'o']
```

The latter one actually used to be a common idiom before the [`String#chars`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-chars) method was introduced.

But it is not legal as an operator. You *can*, of course, create a method with that name:

```
class Foo
  define_method(:'//') do |*args| p __callee__, args end
end
```

But you can only send a corresponding message using reflection:

```
foo = Foo.new

foo.public_send(:'//', 1, 2, 3)
# :"//"
# [1, 2, 3]
```

Not in the normal way:

```
foo.//(1, 2, 3)
# syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
# foo.//(1, 2, 3)
#          ^
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. i was confused as actually it was not supposed to be a comparator in the example i was looking at. Thank you.